# установить maven 3.3.9 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, maven

у меня был установлен maven и maven2. я его снес командой `sudo apt-get remove maven*`
- скачал с офф.сайта последнюю версию `apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip`
- распаковал архив в  `/opt/maven`
- переименовал `apache-maven-3.3.9` на`apache_maven_3.3.9` теперь в указанной директории два каталога `apache_maven_3.3.9` `apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz`
- установил переменную окружения `M2_HOME`  "`export M2_HOME=/opt/maven`"в файл `/etc/profile`
- установил переменную окружения PATH `export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin` в файл `/etc/profile`
   после проверил корректность установки, набрав в командной строке  `mvn -version`

> Приложение 'mvn' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах:
>    * maven
>    * maven2
>   Попробуйте: sudo apt-get install <выбранный пакет>

я выбрал `maven2`
после установки проверяю что получилось. ответ

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
>   Java version: 1.8.0-ea
>   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>   Default locale: ru_UA, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux" version: "3.16.0-51-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"

что я сделал не так? почему версия установилась `2.2.1` а не та которую я прописывал `3.3.9` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какая версия есть в репозитории, та и установилась. Ручная распаковка на это никак не влияет.

Как можно понять, `maven` установлен в папку `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9`, а в `$PATH` прописан каталог `/opt/maven/bin`. Естественно, что система не может его найти. Чтобы исправить ситуацию, либо распакуйте содержимое архива так, чтобы каталог `bin` был в папке `/opt/maven`, либо пропишите

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
```

Чтобы можно было легко менять версии, я рекомендовал бы установить `maven` в каталог `/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9` и создать символическую ссылку `/opt/maven` на этот каталог:

```
ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9 /opt/maven
```

Это избавит от необходимости прописывать новые значения в `$PATH` и `$M2_HOME`. Для смены версии будет достаточно просто удалить ссылку и создать новую, указывающую на другой каталог.

Теперь сделаем `maven` "видимым" в системе. Если этого не сделать, она будет заявлять, что требуемая программа не найдена и предлагать установить её из репозитория. В каталоге `/etc/profile.d` создаём файл с именем, к примеру, `maven.sh` со следующим содержимым:

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Перезагружаем систему или перелогиниваемся (лучше всё же перезагрузить...). Готово! `Maven` работает.

Comment: не помогло. удалил папку `maven` полностью и распаковал заново в `/opt` ,поменял тире на нижнее подчеркивание `/opt/apache_maven_3.3.9` и создал ссылку `/opt/maven` на этот каталог. все равно старая версия `Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)`

Comment: Удалите версию из репозитория: `sudo apt-get purge maven*`.

Comment: сделал все заново. удалил из репозитория. пишет `Приложение 'mvn' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах:
 * maven
 * maven2
Попробуйте: sudo apt-get install <выбранный пакет>`

Comment: `/opt//apache_maven_3.3.9` - папка где лежит мавен
`export M2_HOME=/opt/maven`     
`export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin`

кстати по поводу добавление `M2_HOME` и `PATH` - их в любое место в файле добавлять?

Comment: @makson Обновил ответ.